# Which SE Community is best for aid recalling from childhood a book not pertinent to Literature.SE?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

There's a picture book I'd like help identifying from memory. Literature.SE would hardly be suitable to such a question.

Is a suitable SE site extant?

If not, what would be a suitable genre for a new site which supports identification of such things?

It could be "children's books", but it could also be any miscellany which has no pertinent SE site at time of asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can ask on Literature.SE.**

Your question looks like it would be perfectly fine for Literature.SE - comics are on topic, so why not picture books? They're books too -  just make sure to tag it [story-identification](/questions/tagged/story-identification).

(As you can see, we [decided](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-do-we-think-about-story-identification) that ID-questions are on topic.)

If you *really* want to make sure that your question is on topic, visit [our Meta site](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/) and raise a discussion.

Answer (score 5):

If the book is Science-Fiction or Fantasy, you could try [Science-Fiction & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). They accept identification questions as you can see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification).

Answer (score 4):

**Regarding question #1:** As far as I can see it there currently is no site suited for identification of that, except for Literature.SE. That community has the tag [story identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), so I'd assume that your identification request would be best suited there, as a picture book (presumably) has a story as well as any other book.

**Regarding question #2:** I don't like that idea. Quite a few SE communities already have a tag for the identification of things, for example Movies.SE. Offering identification requests a temporary platform would just cause a mess, as you'd always have to move a lot of questions once a new community goes public (i.e. all "Identify this animal" -> Biology).